# Django Celery email, celery is not working

Tags: python, django, django-celery, celery-task

i am working on django celery for sending the regsitration email ,but the celery is not working correct.

my error is in celery

```
[2014-09-10 19:11:44,349: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@Jeet-PC ready.
[2014-09-10 19:13:38,586: INFO/MainProcess] Received task:       apps.kashmiri.tasks.SignUpTask[17ca2ae1-8c72-426c-babd-470a55ac19
5]
[2014-09-10 19:13:38,936: ERROR/Worker-1] Pool process <Worker(Worker-1, started)> error:     RuntimeError(RuntimeError("App reg
stry isn't ready yet.",), <function model_unpickle at 0x034E4B30>, (('auth', 'User'), [],     <function simple_class_factory at
x034E4AF0>))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 289, in run
sys.exit(self.workloop(pid=pid))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 350, in workloop
req = wait_for_job()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 441, in receive
ready, req = _receive(1.0)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 413, in _recv
return True, loads(get_payload())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\common.py", line 77, in pickle_loads
return load(BytesIO(s))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1450, in model_unpickle
model = apps.get_model(*model_id)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 187, in get_model
self.check_ready()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 119, in check_ready
raise RuntimeError("App registry isn't ready yet.")
RuntimeError: (RuntimeError("App registry isn't ready yet.",), <function model_unpickle at    0x034E4B30>, (('auth', 'User'), [
, <function simple_class_factory at 0x034E4AF0>))
[2014-09-10 19:13:39,233: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-3' pid:7100 exited with 'signal -1'
```

forms.py

```
from apps.kashmiri.tasks import SignUpTask
SignUpTask.delay(user=user)
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'kb.settings')

app=Celery('kb')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind= True)
def debug_task(self):
print('Request:{0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery.registry import tasks
from celery.task import Task
from celery.app import shared_task
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

class SignUpTask(Task):
def run(self, user):
    subject, from_email, to ='Welcome to Kashmiri Bhatta', 'info@seekersguru.com', user.email
    html_content = render_to_string('registration.html',{'user':user.email})
    text_content= strip_tags(html_content)
    msg= EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()

tasks.register(SignUpTask)
```

When i m using  >> **celery -A proj worker -l info**

error for **RuntimeError: (RuntimeError("App registry isn't ready yet.",)**
please help for solving it..

Comment: Are you using `django 1.7`?

Comment: i m using the current version

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs only with `Django 1.7`. It was reported on github and was fixed [recenlty](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2126). Upgrade to latest version of Celery. It should solve the problem

```
pip install celery --upgrade
```